# Info template displayed far from mouse click

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I've consistently noticed in my ESRI webmap that the info template is displayed below the mouse click. For example, if I click on a polygon the one below it is displayed. Sometimes, I cannot get the info template for a feature to display. Here is a screenshot of the issue, the white arrow shows where I clicked, and as displayed, the feature 2 polygons away is highlighted.

Has anyone ever seen this before, or know how to fix?

I'm relatively new to javascript so not sure what to try. What i've done so far is to search for questions similar to mine. My best guess is that maybe something is messing with the mouseY position on click?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this discussion about using map.resize() to fix this bug: https://geonet.esri.com/message/430025#430025

Comment: So, I tried using map.resize and reposition. These are map methods, but I have four feature layers that are loading through checkboxes. I tried including map.resize() and map.reposition() in each feature layers on load event. Still not working. Do you know of any examples that show where/ how these map methods are implemented? Again, thanks much!

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Sure, here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/df9cxsku/ Thanks!

Comment: The service links in the Fiddle were working earlier today, but are now invalid.